# Compare two column in python and return matches in first table

Tags: python, compare, cycle

Help to compare two columns in different tables by cycle and return the matches to the first table.

```
data1:
|name   | revenue |
|-------|---------|
|Alice  | 700     |
|Bob    | 1000    |
|Gerry  | 300     |
|Alex   | 600     |
|Kyle   | 800     |
```

```
data2:
|Name   | revenue |
|-------|---------|
|Bob    | 900     |
|Gerry  | 400     |
```

```
result data1:
|name   | revenue  |  name_result |
|-------|----------|--------------|
|Alice  | 700      |              |
|Bob    | 1000     |  Bob         |
|Gerry  | 300      |  Gerry       |
|Alex   | 600      |              |
|Kyle   | 800      |              |
```

I tried using this code, but got all empty values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def group_category(category):
    for name in data['name']: 
        if name in data2['Name']:
            return name
        else: name = ''
        return name 
data['name_result'] = data['name'].apply(group_category)
```

Comment: which module are you using for manupulating dataframes? `pandas` or `r`?

Comment: I'm using pandas

Comment: have you read [pandas-merging-101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)?

Comment: If you still doesn't find a way then let me know

Comment: How to do it without merge? Later I want use a same code in another task:
 def group_category(category):
    for name in data['name']: 
        if name in data2['Name']:
            return 'organic'
        else: name
        return name 
data['name_result'] = data[data['name'] == 'notorganic'].apply(group_category)

Comment: so you don't want to use merge?

Comment: btw If your query is solved then you can try considering accepting the answer(click on the tick to make it green)...Thnx ***:)***

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
def group_category(category):
    if category in df2['Name'].unique():
            return category
    else:
        return ''

#Finally:
#Since you are going to use this function on Series so used map() in place of apply()
df1['name_result']=df1['name'].map(group_category)
```

OR

via `isin()` and `where()`:

```
df1['name_result']=df1['name'].where(df1['name'].isin(df2['Name']),'')
```

Comment: How can I overwrite a cell if the conditions are the same and leave the old value if everything else?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
df1.loc[df1['name'].isin(df2['name_result'].unique()), 'brand'] = 'Adidas Collection'
```